# Why two wires are used in railway overhead equipment?

Tags: electric-circuits, solid-mechanics, structural-beam

While watching the train video's I came across this overhead wires. After searching on internet I found that both catenary and contact wires carry same voltage and connected by vertical wires called droppers at intermediate points (please refer image 1 [from this video](https://youtu.be/Q5t2RZj1ZkQ?t=8507). In first image it looks like the upper wire is supporting the lower wire but in second image [from this video](https://youtu.be/nKOe2PuERD0?t=1202) they look different. Why two wires are used if only one wire is sufficient to carry current?

[image]

[image]

Comment: seems to be this question should be migrated to engineering https://engineering.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/electrical-engineering

Comment: @annav  he double-posted there, as it happens.

Comment: MechDuck do not double-post

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it's double-posted to Engineering

Comment: ... and there is a much better answer there than I would ever expect here, TBH.

Answer (score 4):

The goal is for the contact wire to be straight, but it is impossible for the wire to actually be straight when it hangs between two supports. (see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Catenary) In order to make a hanging wire more straight, you either need more tension in the wire, or you need more supports.

Tension is limited by the tensile strength of the material. The number of supports is limited by their cost. In your Image_1, notice that there are relatively more *droppers* than there are pylons by the side of the track. The droppers are the support for the contact wire, and there can be as many of them as needed to keep the contact wire straight enough for the application.

The much more expensive pylons can be spaced further apart, because the curve of the catenary wire from which the droppers hang is not a problem for the train.